# No circles for Scatter Plot

Tags: d3.js

The following code should show a scatter plot but the when I check the elements in the developer tools of chrome I only see 1 circle. The full code can be seen here: 
https://bl.ocks.org/centem/db547f011997e64ebf2544e9e22c33ce

I'm creating the circles like this:

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(d3.values(data))
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return x_scale(d["export_val_2010"]); })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return y_scale(d["export_val_2011"]); })
            .attr("r", 5);
```

Comment: Seems like the column *"origin_id"* is missing from the data and that's why the data is turning into an object `undefined: { export_val_2010: 2197123747.77, export_val_2011: 
3008388427.93, id: undefined}` which results in just 1 circle. I just tested in the console adding a dummy *"origin_id"* and it worked. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Shashank.